# rails i18n - How to handle case of a nil date being passed ie l(nil)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working with a lot of legacy data and occasionally a datetime field is nil/null.  This breaks the localization.  Is there a recommended way of fixing this aside from doing this:

```
dt = nil
l(dt) unless dt.nil?
```

Comment: Surely The second line here never executes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no built-in solution. See [post](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/197178).

You can define your own helper that supplies the "nil" human-readable value. Eg:

```
def ldate(dt)
  dt ? l(dt) : t("[???]")
end
```

Answer (score 22):

I think there is a cleaner way to fix this. I monkey patched I18n in an initializer called `relaxed_i18n.rb`

This is the content of that file:

```rb
module I18n

  class << self

    alias_method :original_localize, :localize

    def localize object, options = {}
      object.present? ? original_localize(object, options) : ''
    end

  end

end
```

And this is the RSpec code I used to validate the output of this method:

```rb
require 'rails_helper'

describe 'I18n' do
  it "doesn't crash and burn on nil" do
    expect(I18n.localize(nil)).to eq ''
  end

  it 'returns a date with Dutch formatting' do
    date = Date.new(2013, 5, 17)
    expect(I18n.localize(date, format: '%d-%m-%Y')).to eq '17-05-2013'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 16):

To extend Larry K's answer,

The helper should include a hash to pass options to I18n.

```
def ldate(dt, hash = {})
  dt ? l(dt, hash) : nil
end
```

This allows you to pass options like this:

```
= ldate @term.end_date, format: :short
```

Answer (score 2):

I recently updated an application that uses [jankeesvw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/616863/jankeesvw)'s relaxed i18n method to Ruby 3.1 and found an issue with missing arguments.

The related change in the I18n gem is this: [ruby-i18n/i18n#5eeaad7](https://github.com/ruby-i18n/i18n/commit/5eeaad7fb35f9a30f654e3bdeb6933daa7fd421d#diff-d0c6e2735b6944fb4d9a02f844dcd785eec8cdcc1bec4da6f2ad6596e7b38551).
Also this Ruby 3 change is related: https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2019/12/12/separation-of-positional-and-keyword-arguments-in-ruby-3-0/

Updated the code with this:

```rb
module I18n
  class << self
    alias original_localize localize

    def localize(object, locale: nil, format: nil, **options)
      object.present? ? original_localize(object, locale: locale, format: format, **options) : ''
    end
  end
end
```

And it works again!